# Regex matches must be between another match

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, swiftlint

I would like to match different things, and add condition that these matches must be between specific boundaries,

This is the text

```
protocol SceneDisplayView {
    func displayEmailScreen()
    func displayPasswordScreen()
    func displayNameScreen()
}
```

What i did so far is find my matches, using this regex:

```
(?:^\s*func\s(display\w*)\(\)$)
```

This will end as the following :
[image]

as seen here in the demo: https://regex101.com/r/IuQ7nO/1/

I'm trying to limit these matches that they must be between **`protocol ... {`** and closing bracket **`}`**

so that if there's any floating match outside of these boundaries, they would not show up, how could this be achieved with one regex ?

Comment: Not sure if it is supported, but perhaps `(?:\G(?!^)|\bprotocol\h+\S+\h*{)\R\h*\Kfunc\h+(display\w*)\(\)(?=[^{}]*\})` https://regex101.com/r/8QU8qf/1

Comment: Or if only `\G` is supported using 2 capturing groups `(?:\G(?!^)|\bprotocol\s+\S+\s*{)\r?\n\s*(func\s+(display\w*)\(\))(?=[^{}]*\})` https://regex101.com/r/5AnKJC/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird That almost did it, but there's a small problem, if the first func after protocol bracket does not start with display, it will fail, although there are other func that start with display, between protocol starting and ending brackets,
failing example:
https://regex101.com/r/9xmIxv/1

Comment: Then you can add matching optional word characters before https://regex101.com/r/OC4cNQ/1 I am not sure `\R` and `\K` are supported in swiftlint. Else you  might try https://regex101.com/r/nUpMco/1

Comment: Did that work out?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Apparently only \K is not supported in swiftlint, however, i want to only match func that start with 'display', no matter where they are placed between the brackets,the issue with the current regex is that it always interferes with other func's in other order, failing examples: https://regex101.com/r/y8oIG3/1

Comment: Try it like this, matching the ones that do not start with display, and capture the ones that do https://regex101.com/r/saaZiK/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Swiftlint will catch all matches, there's no option to define which group is the target unfortunately. (including first line which is protocol ..., is also considered as a match and it gets linted)